# In Android Native app failed to create a client socket. Error code:14 Unable to create socket: Permission denied

Tags: java, android, sockets, java-native-interface, native

I have created an Android app calling a method in native code. I'm getting unable to create socket error. Following code is compiled to libconnect.so. I have loaded this library in android app using (System.loadLibrary("connect").

```
#include<gio/gio.h>
#include<glib.h>
#include<android/log.h>
#include "connect.h"

int connect()
{
    GSocketConnection *connection=NULL;
    GSocketClient *client;
    GSocketAddress *address;
    GCancellable *cancellable=NULL;
    GError *error=NULL;
    address = g_network_address_new("192.168.0.1",8080);
    if(address == NULL)
        __android_log_print(6,"Connect Method","Address is not valid");
    client = g_socket_client_new();

    connection = g_socket_client_connect(client, (GSocketConnectable *)address, cancellable, &error);
    __android_log_print(6,"Connect Method","Connecting... ");
    if(connection == NULL)
        __android_log_print(6,"Connect Method","Connection is null");
    if(error != NULL)
        __android_log_print(6,"Connect Method","Error code: %d , Error msg: %s",error->code,error->message);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting the following logs:

```
12-31 11:38:18.032: E/Connect Method(2330): Connecting... 
12-31 11:38:18.032: E/Connect Method(2330): Connection is null
12-31 11:38:18.032: E/Connect Method(2330): Error code: 14 , Error msg: Unable to create socket: Permission denied
```

I have a server running in 192.168.0.1 at port 8080. I need the app to connect to the server and establish TCP connection. What does the error code 14 specify? How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

should have added "android.permission.INTERNET" and "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" android permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Thanks. Perfect answer in hour of need